# Find nested span relative to button

Tags: jquery, dom-traversal

I am not able to get the text value of `.upper` and `.lower` at this example. I already tried

```
var upper = $(this).closest('.col-md-12').find('.lower').text();
```

and

```
var upper = $(this).closest('.col-md-6').find('.lower').text();
```

but they didn't work either

```js
$('#done').on('click', function(e) {

  var upper = $(this).closest('span').find('.lower').text();
  console.log(upper);
  var lower = parseInt($(this).prev().text());
  console.log(lower);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1 text-center">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="col-md-6 text-center"><span class="hidden-color"></span><span class="upper" id="ma-1-0">16</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 text-center lower-box"><span class="hidden-color"></span><span class="lower" id="ma-2-0">13</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <button class="btn btn-success" id="done">Get Upper and Lower</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get to those spans from the `#done` button, traverse up the DOM to a common ancestor before using `find()` to locate the appropriate span.

In my example below, I've used the containing `div.row` as the common ancestor. Given your HTML code, it looks like you could also use `div.col-md-1` because the button and the spans are both descendants thereof.

```js
$('#done').on('click', function(e) {

  var upper = $(this).closest('.row').find('.upper').text(),
      lower = $(this).closest('.row').find('.lower').text();
      
  jQuery('div#output').html('<p>Upper: '+upper+'</p><p>Lower: '+lower+'</p>');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1 text-center">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="col-md-6 text-center"><span class="hidden-color"></span><span class="upper" id="ma-1-0">16</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 text-center lower-box"><span class="hidden-color"></span><span class="lower" id="ma-2-0">13</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <button class="btn btn-success" id="done">Get Upper and Lower</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="output"></div>
```

---

### Edit

Here are some explanations of why code didn't work:

```
var upper = $(this).closest('.col-md-12').find('.lower').text();
```

The button and the spans are children of two different `.col-md-12` elements. The one that is an ancestor of the button is not an ancestor of the spans.

```
var upper = $(this).closest('.col-md-6').find('.lower').text();
```

The button is not a descendant of any `.col-md-6` element. No such closest element exists.

```
var upper = $(this).closest('span').find('.lower').text();
```

There is no span that is an ancestor of the button.